# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/AccessToken$1.class

Tags: facebook, android-studio

When I add facebook sdk dependencies to my android studio project, I have faced the issue :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/AccessToken$1.class
> - Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Please help me to resolve this issue .

Here is my build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.HN.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25'
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```